# How to determine what is occupying hard disk space?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, disk-usage

I have a primary SSD with all my stuff and a 2nd hard drive where I install my games. The SSD has a 120 GB capacity. Until recently, only ~20GB has been used, but something has happened and now 87GB is being used.

How do I determine what's occupying the space?

`df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  9.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /
tmpfs           3.9G  3.9M  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /.snapshots
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /home
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /root
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /var
tmpfs           792M  188K  791M   1% /run/user/1000
```

bottom of: `du -m /  | sort -n | tail -88`:

```
5292    /home/marko/.local/share/Steam
5652    /var
7099    /home/marko/.local
7099    /home/marko/.local/share
14065   /home
14065   /home/marko
192422  /.snapshots
216810  /
```

[image: screenshot of Drives & Locations]

[image: screenshot of visual representation of hard drive space used]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140254/discussion-on-question-by-jifitailu-how-to-determine-what-is-occupying-hard-disk).