# How do I delete /.snapshots

Tags: permissions, delete, helpfile

/.snapshots causes problems in my system and I cant get rid of it
it shows me error that I cant delete read only file
and can anyone even tell my why is this dir 87gb

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions about the same issue [How to determine what is occupying hard disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438218/how-to-determine-what-is-occupying-hard-disk-space)

Comment: Your system is broken, your system-partition is mounted at several mountpoints (/home, /root, /var and /.snapshots) which should not be the case. We can't tell you what happened and why, reinstall your OS.